# “No Activity found to handle Intent” but Intent filter set

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a slash screen starting a MENU and from my menu I'm trying to open a new activity though I get an error when I do so and the app crash.

My Manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MENU" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".settings"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SETTINGS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Then my call for the code of my menu:

```
 Intent settingsIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SETTINGS");
 startActivity(settingsIntent);
```

I tried to change the intent name but it doesn't help.

Log Cap:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1288
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SETTINGS }
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
            at com.learningapp.splash$1.run(menu.java:30)
```

Edit:
calling the class directly work:

```
startActivity(new Intent(currentClass.this, settings.class));
```

Comment: Why are you using the action instead of the class?

Comment: are you sure your activity calls "settings" with that case?

Comment: @323go do you mean this: 
new Intent(String.valueOf(about.class))
I'm pretty new with this stuff.

Comment: @Marcos I assume I call my activities with wathever is in the action of intent-filter. else I messed something!

Comment: Within the app, you would generally [call activities by their class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent) not by action-name. Every basic Android tutorial I've ever seen would do it that way. Where'd you get the idea to use action? (I'm just wondering if there's a bad tutorial out there)

Comment: No, your Activity can be called anything, in the AndroidManifest.xml you should put the exactly name on the name attribute (with package name that can be ommited with a dot to use the application package)

Comment: @Marcos: It was a youtube one, can't recall the name as it was on another computer. I would be happy to get some recommended links though. Still thanks for this point I noted it down.

Comment: @Slamit did you try my answer? If you just want to start settings activity - you dont need intents filters in manifest. Just run it as i write you in the answer.

Comment: Ok it indeed worked with the call from the class. thanks for that.

Comment: @Slamit so, than accept my answer (check green checkbox). I posted you right answer first, a hour ago.

Comment: Yes, I just did :-) thanks for this great help!

Comment: @Slamit You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just start your settings activity, you should use this

```
startActivity(new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, settings.class));
```

Comment: Ok it indeed worked with the call from the class. thanks for that. Though the correct line is: startActivity(new Intent(currentClass.this, settings.class));

Comment: Slamit you dont need to write 'currentClass.this' if you start activity from activity. Its for the inner classes with outer link of the activity.

Comment: Who is down vote this answer? @323go it was you? Maybe you Marcos Vasconcelos? The author just dont know how to start activity. If you dont understand peoples without badges and with raiting "1" - do not touch down vote button, because this guy see this "-1" and he is thinking thats wrong answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your activity is probably not called 'settings'.

At the AndroidManifest.xml you should put the exactly name on the name attribute (with package name that can be ommited with a dot to use the application package)

Comment: I have a settings.xlm in my R.layout, and a settings.java. and a ".settings" in the manifest. just double checked.

Comment: Is it you down vote my answer? If it was you, up vote this, because its the right answer and its exactly what author want.